# How to fix du: cannot access 'directory': No such file or directory?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

This is my code

```
read -r directory
read -r size _ <<<"$( du -sb directory )"
size2m="$( numfmt --from=iec 2M )"
size1m="$( numfmt --from=iec 1M )"

 if [[ ${size} -ge ${size2m} ]]
  then echo "High" readlink -f ${directory} >> ~/ListOfBigDirs.txt

 elif [[ ${size} -le ${size1m} ]]
  then echo "Small"

 elif  [[ ${size} -le ${size2m} ]]
  then echo "Medium"

fi
```

But when I type name of directory it says du: cannot access 'directory': No such file or directory,but actually there is a directory and file that I type on my computer. I don't know how to fix this problem.

```
du: cannot access 'directory': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I can not tell you not to post what is purely a programming question on this site. What I can tell you is you may be better off with this question on a programming site.

Comment: If the permissions of the directory will not allow the user running this script access, then the error will appear. You will need to run this with `sudo` or, better, capture the error and report it cleanly 

Comment: `read -r size _ <<<"$( du -sb directory )"` is not a variable call, but a call to read something actually named `directory`.  It should be something like `$directory` or `${directory}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to reference the variable `$directory` instead of just `directory`.

Also, if you run `du` on system directories, like `/proc` and `/sys`, you may often encounter a situation where files and directories are created and removed so fast that they become missing with the same error message.

The best solution for me is to redirect error messages from `du` to the null device.

```
$( du -sb "$directory" 2> /dev/null )
```

However, note that the size reported for these directories also doesn't make any sense. So it's probably best to exclude these directories completely in some way.

If this doesn't concern system directories, just make sure to reference your variables correctly.